# gethostbyname buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, gethostbyname

I study about GHOST or CVE-2015-0235 vulnerability. I find out that my system is vulnerable. I write a test program to see the effect of this. but I cant see any thing. hear is my attemps:

```
    user@debian:~$ uname -a 
    Linux debian 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3 i686 GNU/Linux
    user@debian:~$ ./GHOST
    vulnerable
    user@debian:~$ cat ghost-example.c 
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define len 2000000

    struct{
    char buf[len];
    char canary[32];
    }buffer;

    void main()
    {
        memset(buffer.buf,'9',len);
        buffer.buf[len-1]='\0';
        strcpy(buffer.canary,"the vulnerable part of program\n");
        gethostbyname(buffer.buf);
        printf(buffer.canary);
    }
    user@debian:~$ gcc ghost-example.c -o ghost-example
    user@debian:~$ ./ghost-example 
    the vulnerable part of program
```

I cant find out what happen? what is the difference between gethostbyname() ,gethostbyname_r(), gethostbyname2() or gethostbyname2_r. I have a lot of study about this. can anybody help me?
thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly are you having trouble with ?

Comment: `char buf[2000000];` are you sure? it seems too big

Comment: when I call gethostbyname_r in GHOST program it cause overwrite on memory in canary variable but  not in this case. hear is GHOST.c source :  https://webshare.uchicago.edu/orgs/ITServices/itsec/Downloads/GHOST.c

Comment: it should be long to overwrite memory.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you aren't using a large enough buffer? I find this difficult to believe, since `2000000` is huge in the world of buffer overflows.

Alternatively, by coincidence a `ret` address of `0x39393939` or `0x3939393939393939` is perfectly valid. I find this difficult to believe. You should be seeing a segfault with a trace that ends somewhere around that address.

Most likely, `gethostbyname` isn't overflowing. Perhaps your diagnosis is incorrect, and your machine is no longer susceptible.